# How to convert IF statement into CASE statement?

Tags: sql, if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, alteryx

I want to convert the following `IF` statement into `CASE` statement, since it doesn't work in `Alteryx`, which is using a `Snowflake` database.

```
IF LEFT([SN],3)="CAT" AND Length([SN])=17 THEN RIGHT([SN],8) ELSE [SN] ENDIF
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Using CASE expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SN LIKE 'CAT%' AND LENGTH(SN) = 17 THEN RIGHT(SN,8) 
            ELSE SN
       END
```

or [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html):

```
SELECT IFF(SN LIKE 'CAT%' AND LENGTH(SN) = 17, RIGHT(SN,8), SN)
```

Comment: IFF SELECT IFF(SN LIKE 'CAT%' AND LENGTH(SN) = 17, RIGHT(SN,8), SN) Worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: @Evoz Great to hear it https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer